# Jquery on(), reference dynamically generated element

Tags: jquery

```
$('body').on('input', $('#images_finder').find('input[type=search]'), function (event) {
});
```

Consider the code above, I was (wrongly?) expecting $(this) within this block to point to the element matching the selector I'm passing, but it points to body instead.

If I try to find the element again it doesn't work

```
$('body').on('input', $('#images_finder').find('input[type=search]'), function (event) {
    console.log($('#images_finder').find('input[type=search]').prop('tagName'));
    // returns undefined

});
```

What's the correct way to reference it?

Comment: `on`'s second parameter should be a valid `CSS` selector not a `jQuery` object (which is what you're currently passing). [.on() Docs](https://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: As above, passing a jquery object will pass it as the `data` parameter:  here's an example where typing in either input will output "search" as the `event.data[0].id`  https://jsfiddle.net/3yxobq1h/

Comment: The correct way would be: `$('body').on('input', '#images_finder input[type=search]', function (event) {`